# Express: How can I read a value from the configuration

Tags: node.js, configuration, express

I am a NodeJS newbie and have a really simple question.

I want to store the port of the server in the application configuration. I use something like this to store it in the app config:

```
app.configure(function(){
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.bodyParser());

  // My configuration:
  app.set('port', 80);
});
```

But how can I use the value of port? I cannot find an answer in the [Express documentation](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#configuration).

Something like `console.log('Port: ' + app.get('port'));` doesn't work (`TypeError: Array.prototype.toString is not generic`).

Is there a better/other way to store a simple config value with the express framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Express 2.x.x then take a look at the definition of the function set(key, value): 
https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/2.5.11/lib/http.js#L436

`Line 444: this.settings[setting] = val;`

So this should works:

```
console.log(app.setting['port']);
```

Answer (score 2):

Even simpler: `app.set(setting)` with only one argument returns the value of `setting`. This has the advantage of not using implementation-dependent features, and will work in 3.x.x as well